# По клику вставить картинку в popup из элемента где находится кнопка

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет.
Есть карточки товаров со структурой:

```
<article class="cards__article article">
    <div class="article__img">
        <img class="article__pic" src="icons/pepper.svg" alt="Pepper">
    </div>
    <div class="article__description">
        <h2 class="article__title">Pepper</h2>
        <p class="article__text">Goes well with pasta</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article__btns">
        <button class="article__button buy-btn">Buy</button>
        <button class="article__button info-btn">Info</button>
    </div>
</article>

<div class="b-pop">
    <div class="b-pop__inner">
        <div class="b-pop__body">
            <button class="b-pop__close-btn"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

По клику на кнопку с классом article__button появляется popup.
В карточках есть div с img. Хочу, что бы в popup отображался div с img, но только из соответствующей карточки товара.
Реализовать хочу на чистом JS.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Спасибо

Comment: Где ваш popup? Как пытались это реализовать и с чем возникли сложности?

Comment: @SwaD разметку popup добавил в описание вопроса. С реализацией отображения popup нет. Сложности возникли при попытке реализовать то, что я описал в вопросе. Не могу найти информацию, которая натолкнула бы на то, как это сделать.

Comment: @SwaD я пытаюсь понять как обратиться к div с img из той же карточки товара, где и кнопка, по которой был клик.

Comment: [Например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475466/) или [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1494569/) - Вешаете слушателя на кнопку и при клике берете значение src из img текущего блока и вставляете в нужное место в попапе. А вот тут можно найти пример, как динамически рендерить данные и привязываться к ним [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1494915) или [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480745)

Comment: @SwaD спасибо большое. Буду смотреть.